# Convergence in measure iff every subsequence has a convergant subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, sequence-of-function

My task is to show that on a finite measure space $(X,A)$, if $f_n \to f$ in measure, then **every** subsequence of $\{f_n\}$ has a subsequence that converges to $f$ almost everywhere.

I believe I was successful in showing the converse, but one thing confuses me:

I saw proof in my textbook that if $f_n \to f$ in measure, then there is a subsequence that converges to $f$ a.e.

However my problem asks that **every** subsequence of $f_n$ have a convergant subsequence.

I think I'm getting myself confused after thinking of subsequences of subsequences for too long, and a fresh take on things would be very helpful.

I think I remember seeing someone say that it should be a consequence of Egorov's Theorem, but I don't see how that is since it assumes pointwise convergence a.e. so how could it be used to prove it?

Comment: If $f_n \to f$ in measure, wouldn't every subsequence of $(f_n)_n$ also converge to $f$ in measure? And thus every subsequence has a subsequence that converges to $f$ a.e.?

Comment: @Demophilus Ah! so simple! I was making it way more complicated than it had to be.